# .Net MVC WebAPI: making some methods "admin only"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

.Net 4.6.1

I am still very new to .Net and MVC.  Trying my hand at creating an API and then what will really be a javascript app that will consume the API.  I've got a thousand questions but I will focus on one area for this.  In the API code I see the methods that support the CRUD operations.  I will want the read-only API methods open to the world but the editing methods need authorization.

Is there a best practice here?  Should I create two APIs?  One for the "public" read actions and another for the admin operations?  Can I keep one API and force the edit actions to require auth?  I've seen a discussion of using API keys -- perhaps have API keys for the admin methods?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading these articles as a starting point (and some of the other articles in the same section!):
[Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)
[Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

You can turn on or off authentication for web API at virtually any level.
Globally, per controller, or per action method.
You can also override something, so if you turn it on globally, you can turn it off for a particular controller or method.

So to answer part of your question, I can't see that there is a need to create two APIs, but the articles linked will help.